# React, S3, and CloudFront Versioning for Deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

**First problem:**

I have a static webpage hosted on S3, a CloudFront distribution pointing to this S3 bucket, and an A record on my domain pointing to this CloudFront distro. I also have some API Gateway and Lambda and DynamoDB stuff going on.

This webpage is a React app following the `create-react-app` template. As such, when I `yarn build`, all of the js and css fragments are cache-busted nicely with these random `main.d74fc389.chunk.js` names. However, importantly, the `index.html` (and other static files) are not.

When I `aws s3 sync build/ s3://xxxx`, everything gets uploaded nicely, but the cloudfront root is still pointing at the old cached `index.html`!

What can I do about this so that my automatic deployment script (basically just `yarn build && aws s3 sync build/ s3://xxxxxx` works properly?

I am pointing my domain to CloudFront rather than to the straight S3 website because I want a TLS certificate. I have therefore denied access in my policies to the S3 bucket to anyone except the CloudFront OAI.

**Second problem**:

*I've solved this by setting up a default object in CloudFront.*

<strike>For some reason I keep getting `access denied` errors on my `https://cloudfront.xxxxxx.xxx` (and therefore on my `https://mydomain.xxx`, but accessing `https://mydomain.xxx/index.html` and any other item (including the newly uploaded items, as evidenced by the updated javascript!) has absolutely no issue. Wtf? Here is my S3 policy:</strike>

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1631694343564",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxxxx/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This was literally autogenerated by CloudFront, so I have no idea how it could be incorrect.

I do have my bucket set to serve a static website, but have declined access to s3:GetObject to the general public, so this URL does nothing. The origin I have set up for my CloudFront is the S3's REST api (i.e. `xxxxxx.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.xxx`) rather than the bucket's website URL (`http://xxxxxxx.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.xxx/`).

*The `.com` in URLs was replaced with `.xxx` because of StackOverflow rules*

Answer (score 1):

Wait for the TTL or invalidate your cache.

`aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id E2FXXXXXX4N0MS --paths "/*"`

This may not be suitable if you are doing lots of deployments as there are some limits and costs.

[AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html)

Comment: Maybe read up on AWS amplify as well

Comment: must mention that distribution_ID is the cloudfront distribution ID like E2FXXXXXX4N0MS, "distribution_ID" looks like arguments