# Static websites content are not reflecting immediately after files are updated in S3 bucket

Tags: angular, amazon-s3

I have created a S3 bucket in AWS and added my Angular projects dist folder into it. On this S3 bucket, I have enabled Static Website and grant public access to all my files. So by this, I can access my Angular projects front end using this configured S3 url.
Problem is:
Whenever I upload new changes in this bucket and tries to access this buckets url then the changes are not reflecting immediately.

Can you please suggest any way by which it is possible?

Comment: Are you using cloudfront as a cdn or custom domain?

Comment: I am using cloudfront

Comment: When the site is browsed for the first time, cloud-front will `GET` the files from your bucket and then cache the file to the edge location closest to the user for subsequent requests.

Comment: If you are doing lots of deployments you should take a look at AWS Amplify. You can connect it to a range of src repos and configure the site to auto-build when a branch is published.

Answer (score 0):

Same as [React, S3, and CloudFront Versioning for Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69202315/react-s3-and-cloudfront-versioning-for-deployment/69208255#69208255)

> Wait for the TTL or invalidate your cache.
>
> ```
> aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id E2FXXXXXX4N0MS --paths "/*"
> ```
>
> This may not be suitable if you are doing lots of deployments as there are some limits and costs.
>
> [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html)